# How to find child tables that inherit from another table in PSQL

Tags: postgresql

In PSQL, is there a good way of finding all the tables that inherit from another table?  Ideally, I could get the data from a SQL query, but at this point, I'd be happy with any reliable method.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

What do you mean "from sql query"? Does it mean `SELECT`ing from `pg_inherits` is not good enough for you?

```
SELECT pg_inherits.*, c.relname AS child, p.relname AS parent
FROM
    pg_inherits JOIN pg_class AS c ON (inhrelid=c.oid)
    JOIN pg_class as p ON (inhparent=p.oid);
```

Comment: When I wrote "sql query", I meant something I could pass to PSQL on the command line, as opposed to something like \d that must be run interactively.  So selecting from pg_inherits is a good start.  Where can I find a table listing table names and their oids?

Comment: Das is perfekt!  Vielen dank!

Comment: Watusimoto - \d can be passed to psql on the command line as well :)

Comment: `\d+ _parentTable_` will append a list all child tables from the command-line console

Answer (score 11):

If you also need the schema names:

```
SELECT cn.nspname AS schema_child, c.relname AS child, pn.nspname AS schema_parent, p.relname AS parent
FROM pg_inherits 
JOIN pg_class AS c ON (inhrelid=c.oid)
JOIN pg_class as p ON (inhparent=p.oid)
JOIN pg_namespace pn ON pn.oid = p.relnamespace
JOIN pg_namespace cn ON cn.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE p.relname = 'your table name' and pn.nspname = 'your schema name'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find all child's from the master partition you can simply execute it like:

```
SELECT relname
FROM pg_class,pg_inherits
WHERE pg_class.oid=pg_inherits.inhrelid
AND inhparent
IN (SELECT oid FROM pg_class WHERE relname='your_master_partition')
ORDER BY relname;
```