# pg_dump vs COPY (SELECT * FROM my_table)

Tags: sql, pg-dump, postgresql-9.0

I need to copy the contents of a table from one database to another database with an identical table which is currently empty.

I plan to dump the table data from the old table and then simply import it to the empty table in the new database.  However, I ran into some behavior I don't understand using pg_dump.

I try to dump the table data to a file with the command:

```
pg_dump -a -t '"my_table"' my_database > /tmp/my_table.sql
```

This works, but I only get 8 records and there are over 1000 records in the table if I view the table like so:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

So, I tried to use the COPY command to generate a .csv file and I see similar behavior:

```
COPY my_table TO '/tmp/my_table.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;
```

I get the same 8 records as pg_dump. But, with:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM my_table) TO '/tmp/my_table.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;
```

I get all 1266 records.

I would assume these commands should all return the same data, but obviously, I'm wrong.  What is the difference?

Comment: That's pretty crazy. Can you show the output?

Comment: how many records in `/tmp/my_table.sql`?

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible that `my_table` is part of an inheritance hierarchy? I ask because http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/sql-copy.html#AEN58984 has this:

> COPY only deals with the specific table named; it does not copy data to or from child tables. Thus for example `COPY table TO` shows the same data as `SELECT * FROM ONLY table`. But `COPY (SELECT * FROM table) TO ...` can be used to dump all of the data in an inheritance hierarchy.

You should be able to check by running:

```
SELECT * FROM ONLY my_table;
```

If that returns just the 8 records then we're on the right track, and we just need to find the child tables (for which [How to find child tables that inherit from another table in PSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461722/how-to-find-child-tables-that-inherit-from-another-table-in-psql) will be helpful).

If not then I'm not sure - I wondered if maybe Rules or Triggers were getting involved, but I can't see how at the moment. Still, maybe it gives someone else an idea...?