# right arrow on the table tree in pgadmin

Tags: pgadmin

In pgadmin, what is the meaning of the small right arrow on the table tree?
please refer to below image for table 'meetingtype_r'

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are no confirmed answer.

There is an open thread in postgres support in below link. you can follow for most updated answer.

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/MN2PR01MB5327735A00F3187C0F728B9FCFA60%40MN2PR01MB5327.prod.exchangelabs.com**strong text**

Some of the options that I have already validated.

- its not a icon to show inheritance
- its not an icon for trigger

one of the comments that I could not totally reject is below:

" My thought is that icon started appearing with the expanded support for partitioned tables, so is this a table that is partitioned or a table that holds partitioned data "

Comment: Are you sure about this ? can you provide please some documentation link ?

Comment: Is meetingtype_r a time series table ?

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to locate any documentation regarding the icons in pgadmin, but based on the icon table-inherited.svg, it means that the table is inherited.

check `web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\databases\schemas\tables\static\img\`

[image]

Edited:

Another way to confirm my conclusion is to run this query (thanks to [Michael Krelin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1461750/5733399) ) and you will see the name of your table with an inheritance appear

```
SELECT pg_inherits.*, c.relname AS child, p.relname AS parent
FROM
pg_inherits JOIN pg_class AS c ON (inhrelid=c.oid)
JOIN pg_class as p ON (inhparent=p.oid);
```

One possible way that this icon appear is when a table is defined as a time series table, then pgadmin system is creating hypertable chunks under the _timescaledb_internal schema.

Comment: there was no inheritance in my table yet the icon was shown.

Comment: @Monu how did you confirm that there is no inheritance in the table ? by pgadmin or did you use a query ? could you show us ?  My answer reply the main question with a fact of what I found!

Answer (score 1):

Table inheritance.

- An arrow to the right tells you that it is a parent table.
- An arrow to the left tells you that it is a child table.

To know the child table of a parent:

```
SELECT cn.nspname AS schema_child, c.relname AS child, 
       pn.nspname AS schema_parent, p.relname AS parent
FROM pg_inherits 
  JOIN pg_class AS c ON (inhrelid=c.oid)
  JOIN pg_class as p ON (inhparent=p.oid)
  JOIN pg_namespace pn ON pn.oid = p.relnamespace
  JOIN pg_namespace cn ON cn.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE p.relname = 'table_name' and pn.nspname = 'schema_name'
```

You can check it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The right arrow showed up for me when I referred to the so-adorned table as a reference for the column layout for another table I created.

The table that inherited the column layout has a left arrow on it.

With one reference this is informative but could get messy if there were several tables with inherited characteristics.